# Cross Post if you get no answer?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, cross-posting

I searched for the phrase "Cross Post" here in meta stack overflow. Still unclear on how it applies to my current circumstances.

I have a problem. I went to some length to document the entire procedure (with screen caps at every step) and posted a question about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/595085/bluetooth-remove-failed-windows-8) three days ago. Still no answer. Will my reputation be hurt if I post it in the regular stack overflow ?

Perhaps a better question is: Where are the experts who know what to do in this case ?

For the moment, I want to know if it's okay to post a shorter version of the question to other Stack Exchange sites, and link to the SuperUser question to provide the details.

Comment: If you do cross-post hardly anyone will notice(unless you bring undue attention to your question)

Comment: @SamIam Really? That is your advice?

Comment: I had a similar situation. I notified a mod about having it moved, but was told to wait a few days then post on another site. See http://superuser.com/q/561921/113542

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not a programming question at all, so it's entirely inappropriate to post it on Stack Overflow.  It would (or should) be closed as off topic if you tried.

It looks like the question is most certainly one that belongs on SU, and not on any other site.

In situations where a post is in scope on multiple sites this can be debatable, but I see no other sites for which this question would also be on-topic for, so in your case it's a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So then, SuperUser is the right place for that kind of question ? Guess I'm hosed on this one. Whatever, whatever, thanks for heading me off at the pass before I took a negative hit on my reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is off topic on Stack Overflow, if you post it there it will be quickly closed and probably downvoted.

Generally speaking cross posting should be avoided. While it's not impossible for a question to fit on more than one sites, it's highly improbable. Even in the rare occasion where a question is on topic on more than one sites, you should still try to tailor it for each site and not just copy paste it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not OK to post to 2 sites, where 1 site would contain full problem description and the 2nd will have only reference to it.

If the post is off-topic, it's very likely it will be migrated, so you don't have to do any action.

If the migration doesn't take place, but you get comments it's off-topic, it's worth considering asking the question to proper site.

The only valid condition to ask the question on 2 sites is IMHO when your question is really interdisciplinary and on-topic on both sites, but don't ask the same question. Formulate 2 questions, each of them accenting the aspect that is essencial to given site.

For example, if your question is about both administrative and programming issue, you can concentrate on programming aspect on SO and on administrative aspect on SuperUser. This would build 2 unique and independent questions, though both emerging form the same issue.